# How to trust a jar file in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, java-applet, jar

We are testing a java application with an unsigned jar file (which we'll sign in time). One tester, on being prompted with standard security warning, selected NO to not trust an application jar file.

We cannot seen to find where to change the setting so that the jar file is either trusted, or we get the dialog about trusting it again.

We've gone into the control panel and cleared the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all jar files from `\Users\<account name>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache` ( on Win 7/Vista ). Run the application and it should prompt with the warning